# Mutiple actions spark casuing to failures

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, bigdata, rdd

I'm new to Spark.
I encountered some problems with part of about saving df to Hive table.

```
def insert_into_hive_table(df: DataFrame, table_name: str):
        # for debugging - this action is working and contain 1528 rows
        logger.info(f'check if df in insert_into_hive_table can do action before saving')
        df = df.persist()
        logger.info(f'df count is {df.count()} rows')

        with spark_conf_context("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict"), spark_conf_context("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic"), spark_conf_context("spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class", "org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter"), spark_conf_context("spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass", "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol"):
            df.select(output_cols).write.insertInto(table_name)
        
        # for debbuging - this action is failing
        logger.info(f'check if df in insert_into_hive_table can do action after saving')
        df = df.persist()
        logger.info(f'df count is {df.count()} rows')
```

my original function was just the middle part of the function.
the first count and the saving operation is working fast and I see the correct result in the Hive table.
but the last count fails all the time on broadcast timeout, and I don't even know where the broadcast is happening.

some details which may affect:

1. I'm getting this error:

```
 No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

while saving to the hive.
2. my default partition number is 200.
3. I'm using CDP and spark 2.4.8
4. I increased already the broadcast timeout to 720 secs
5. the table contain 2 partitions

edit:
I see that immediately after the insertInto, I can't see the df on my spark UI storage (but before insertInto I do see), any suggestions?

Comment: if you just want to save the spark df in hive table then just use the following df.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").saveAsTable("Giveyourtablename")

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to save the spark df in hive table then just use the following df.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").saveAsTable("Giveyourtablename")

Comment: I want to append
df.write.mode("append").format("delta").saveAsTable("Giveyourtablename")
is raising the same problem